# Magento custom shipping amount

Tags: magento-enterprise, shipping

I am importing orders from a 3rd party application, and I need to be able to set a custom shipping amount, ignoring everything in Magento.

Here's what I tried, without success:

```
$quote           = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId($storeId);
$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();

$shippingAddress
    ->addData($addressDetails['shipping']) // shipping data I need to save - city, region, etc
    ->setCollectShippingRates(true)
    ->collectShippingRates()
    ->setShippingMethod('tablerate_bestway')
    ->setPaymentMethod('cashondelivery');

$shippingAmount = mt_rand(0, 20); // value doesn't matter

// basically everything I found related to the price in the shipping address
$shippingAddress->setBaseShippingAmount($shippingAmount);
$shippingAddress->setShippingAmount($shippingAmount);
$shippingAddress->setTotalAmount('subtotal', $shippingAmount);
$shippingAddress->setData('shipping_incl_tax', $shippingAmount);
$shippingAddress->setData('base_shipping_incl_tax', $shippingAmount);
$shippingAddress->setData('shipping_taxable', $shippingAmount);
$shippingAddress->setData('base_shipping_taxable', $shippingAmount);
$shippingAddress->setData('shipping_amount_for_discount', $shippingAmount);
$shippingAddress->setData('base_shipping_amount_for_discount', $shippingAmount);

// maybe the rates have something to do with this ... 
foreach ($shippingAddress->getShippingRatesCollection() as $rate) {
    $rate->setPrice($shippingAmount);
}
```

Regardless of the value of the shipping amount I want to set, the Magento calculated value is used.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

I imagine that you create orders programmatically:

[Set Shipping cost order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293734/magento-set-shipping-cost-when-create-order-programmatically)

This way allow you to set price of shipping to any value.

Answer (score 0):

You can update shipping cost through these line of code:-

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($incrementId, 'increment_id');
$shippingprice = 30;//custom shipping price
$order->setShippingAmount($shippingprice);
$order->setBaseShippingAmount($shippingprice);
$order->setGrandTotal($order->getGrandTotal() + $shippingprice); //adding shipping price to grand total
$order->save();
```

It will help you.